# O que significa "fazer pela vida"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto, expressões-idiomáticas, sinônimos, expressões-equivalentes

Estava a ter uma conversa e surgiu esta expressão que um padre disse ao meu bisavô paterno

> Não faças pela vida que ficas tramado.

Enquanto tentava explicar o significado de "fazer pela vida", as minhas palavras não captam a completa essência. Também não encontrei nada pela net a esse respeito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão "fazer pela vida" é utilizada na seguinte entrada do Priberam:

> [Mourejar | *v. intr.*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mourejar)
>
> Trabalhar sem descanso; **fazer pela vida.** = MOIREJAR

que, por sua vez, é indicada como sinónimo de:

> [Xurdir | *v. intr.*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/xurdir)
>
> [Regionalismo]  Lutar pela vida; trabalhar sem descanso. = MOUREJAR

Ainda que ambas as palavras sejam muito mais obscuras e desconhecidas que a expressão **"fazer pela vida"**, compreende-se a partir destas entradas que a expressão pode ser entendida como **"lutar pela vida"/"trabalhar sem descanso"** ou, simplesmente, **esforçar-se.**

No entanto, na falta de expressões equivalentes que "captem a completa essência" da expressão original, sugiro que se explique o significado por contextualização, por exemplo, desta forma:

> Só sabes mandriar. Não trabalhas, nem estudas. Não achas que já estava na altura de **fazeres pela vida**?

Em que se entende que fazer pela vida significa o mesmo que pôr-se ao trabalho, ou esforçar-se por alcançar algo.